# Как массово установить приложения из Google Play на смартфон? (около 5 - 7 приложений)

Tags: android

Появилась необходимость автоматически устанавливать на смартфон приложения. В идеале нажать 1 кнопку после чего нужные приложения по очереди устанавливаются без необходимости каждый раз нажимать кнопку подтверждения установки. (чтобы это было максимально автоматически)

Возможно ли такое вообще и если да, то не могли бы вы подсказать где об этом можно почитать? Пока что на просторах гугла я не смог найти ничего подходящего к сожалению (в android разработке я, к сожалению практически ничего не знаю и не понимаю).

Возможно можно написать какой нибудь apk как bat-ник на винде, который будет переходить к примеру по ссылке, скачивать приложение, его открывать, устанавливать и автоматом нажимать кнопку подтверждения установки.

Comment: Не хотел бы я иметь смартфон с такой ОС, которая может без моего участия автоматически устанавливать неизвестные мне приложения... А вообще, зачем вам это понадобилось? Возможно есть другое решение вашей "проблемы"?

Comment: Это нужно чтобы в магазине если человек купил приложения он мог их установить автоматически нажав одну кнопку, а не в ручную или по usb

Comment: Даже если такое возможно - это не безопасно. На сколько я знаю, достичь такого результата можно только собственной сборкой (firmware) android. Нужно предоставить пользователю выбор, какие приложения он хочет поставить, а какие нет. Пусть высвечивается в вашем приложении, что доступны такие то программы.

Comment: Такое могут делать MDM агенты (Android for Work, AirWatch), но это не ваш случай. Если у вас рандомный сторонний пользователь -- никак.

Comment: Благодарю за ответы! А к примеру adb никак не выйдет использовать? Читал что его можно подключить по wifi к пк и с пк устанавливать удаленно приложения....
Никак нельзя разместить adb драйвер на сервере и с телефона к нему обращаться? 
(возможно глупость написал)